# A Best Approach of Creating Two Front-End Websites With A Same Base-End

Tags: jhipster

Working on a new project, I need to create two sets of the front end with a same back-end code base and data. The second set of front end can be accessed through a sub-domain name such as secondfrontend.mywebsite.com. What will be the best approach between two sets of front end codes and two basic pages of the single page applications? I am going to use Vue for the front end as it is the simplest Javascript framework in the current JHispter project.

Comment: Not really a jhipster question

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project is using JHIpster.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the JHipster REST API from any consumer you want (SPA, native mobile, ...). Since you have 2 webapps and not written in Angular, you would probably serve them from another http server than the Spring Boot app as static contents (lots of solutions there depending on your infra. Eg: Apache/Nginx, CloudFront, Express, ...). Note : If the fronts and the back are not on the same domain, you will have to take care of setting the CORS accordingly in the Jhipster app.
Also note that JHipster does a lot of optimizations when serving the static content (gzip, set caching headers, ...) so you will have to reproduce these optimizations in your server if you want optimal performance.

Comment: Ideally, I should create two websites for the two big groups of end users. We need to roll out the app quickly. I need to all functionalities in a single app with two entry points. Any solutions need to be in the scope of the given technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of expansion, I would definitely use a REST API with some sort of load balancing/caching sitting just before the entry point of backend. For sub domain, Cross Site Origin (CORS) should be able to take care of your problem.

Although, I have never used JHipster, but Spring with `RestController` that serve as rest API is a very nice option if you are working with very large backend. Just bare in mind that Spring Security takes in a urlencoded HTTP Body (Although through some Added filter JSON can also be parse in).

Vue as a front end is also a very nice option for SPA.

Comment: The back end of a JHipster is Spring Boot. Rest is the communication channel between a Javascript front end and back end. I don't understand a solution I am seeking for has anything to do with load balance and caching.

Comment: Load balancing was mention since I assume that you will get more traffic to the backend and might get a performance hit. (hence, the expansion to 2 platform).